# byte[] to image android

Tags: android, image, byte

My issue is as follows :
I have stored a few pictures into the sqlite database, using the blob format, which seems to work ok. now i want to get my pictures out of the DB and put then back into images... to complicate the matter, their format is variable (png, jpg, maybe something else, im not sure)
Is there a way of doing so in android?

thank you

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/intl/it/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray) method:

```
byte[] blob=c.getBlob("yourcolumnname");
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob,0,blob.length);
ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Look at [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0eca3333d32a314c) thread too.

Comment: that's exactly what i did, but i was using drawable so I added a cast, but i don't think i need it. thanks for the help guys. thanks for the detailed explanation here

Comment: decodeByteArray method return null if the image could not be decoded; check your code that store to db.

Comment: this doesn't work on motorola! decodeByteArray says that I should send valid data it is not image data that I am sending. why? how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Use [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)).

Comment: thx for the hint, i'll have a closer look and come back to you if I don't find.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to convert the array of bytes to Drawable directly. It is the best format to use in Android. Bitmaps generated leaks in the past.

```
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(ARRAY_BYTES), null);
```