# Display images into grid view in android application

Tags: android

I stored the images into the databases with blob type. I want to display those images into grid view. I'm a newbie in android. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray will do the trick. see this answer - [byte[] to image android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714700/byte-to-image-android) which is more or less the same as what you want to do. Read the blob from your database in

```
byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("yourimageblob")); 
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob,0,blob.length);
ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

To then show the images in gridview, the answer is here - [Showing Images in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026928/showing-images-in-gridview)

Hope this helps