# Convert image to byte array and viceversa

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send an image as byte array through android, and convert it back to png file on server side, I'm getting `IllegalArgumentException` on server side.

This is my android code which converts image to byte array and sends it as request to server:

```
 GestureOverlayView gestureView = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signaturePad);

            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getGesture().toBitmap(100, 100, 8, Color.WHITE));

            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("signature.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

            byte[] image_byte = fos.toString().getBytes();//Base64.encode(fos.toString().getBytes(), 0);

            String strImage = image_byte.toString();
```

This is my server side program:

```
String imageString = request.getParameter("SignatureImage");
    byte[] imageByte = imageString.getBytes();
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

        //Getting exception at this line
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File(
                "E:/signature/signature.png"));
        /*BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte));
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new File("E:/signature/signature.jpg"));*/
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception on server is:

```
12:39:40,990 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/APDTest].[ImageRetrieve]] Servlet.service() for servlet ImageRetrieve threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: im == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1457) [:1.6.0_32]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1521) [:1.6.0_32]
    at com.apd.test.ImageRetrieve.doPost(ImageRetrieve.java:52) [:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.1.0.Final]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your writing the image to a file output stream on your client side, which will store the contents into a physical file. You are then trying to convert the `toString` representation of `FileOutputStream` as the image content. This won't work, the `toString` method of that class doesn't give you the contents that were written to the stream, it just prints a barely helpful message like this:

> java.io.FileOutputStream@761eec35

I believe what you intended to do was use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` - this class ***does*** allow you to retrieve the actual contents written via its `toString` method.

On Android side (snippet):

```
Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(gestureView.getGesture().toBitmap(100,
        100, 8, Color.WHITE));

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2056);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

On server side (snippet):

```
String imageString = request.getParameter("SignatureImage");
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);

try {
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
    BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);

    ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", new File(
            "E:/signature/signature.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

**Converting image into  Byte:** For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513976/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-and-byte-array-to-base64-string-in-android)

```
                  yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(galleryFilePath);     
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
              yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
              byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

**Converting Byte into image:** For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714700/byte-to-image-android)

```
                         final String encodedImage = response.toString();
           byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
         decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: I'm not trying to save image and load it back, I'm trying to capture signature using gesture over lay view and send it to server on click of button..