# convert byteArray to bitmap retrieved from sqlite

Tags: android, image, bitmap, arrays

I am trying to save image in sqlite database and then retrieve it later. I have stored it in form of byte[]. BUt bitmap is not being formed!

Storing images: (blob type)

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(arr[i]);
myLogo = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
b = stream.toByteArray();
```

My code for retrieving:

```
byte[] Image;
Image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("img_str"));
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Image, 0,Image.length, options);
arr_img.add(decodedByte);

System.out.println("Image = " + Image);
System.out.println("decodedByte = " + decodedByte);
```

Logcat:

```
07-22 07:15:55.482: D/skia(19319): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
07-22 07:15:55.482: I/System.out(19319): Image = [B@4057ea48
07-22 07:15:55.482: I/System.out(19319): decodedByte = null
07-22 07:15:55.521: D/dalvikvm(19319): GC_EXPLICIT freed 114K, 50% free 2871K/5639K,external 5406K/5783K, paused 43ms
07-22 07:15:55.541: D/skia(19319): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
07-22 07:15:55.541: I/System.out(19319): Image = [B@40577aa0
07-22 07:15:55.541: I/System.out(19319): decodedByte = null
```

please help as i am clueless why this is not working. thanks

Comment: why are you storing image in db? You could simply store the location of the image file in DB instead of the complete image.

Comment: i am storing image prepopulated database. the app will just display it!

Comment: Refer this for storing images and retrieving images.[Refer][1]

[Refer This][2]

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620401/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-bitmap
[2]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790104/how-to-storebitmap-image-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: Are you sure the images have been encoded in the same way that you are trying to decode them?

Comment: I did not encode the images.. please have a look at the edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15805462/1835764. check that

Comment: @Nirmal: but I am not encoding the array

Comment: @Pooja try that it will work.

Comment: @Nirmal: sorry still not working

Comment: are you getting the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was not with the conversion but the way how i was storing it..

I used prepared statement to insert values.. bindBlob() did the job

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO demoImage (img_name,img_str) VALUES(?,?)";

    SQLiteStatement insertStmt = dbsqlite.compileStatement(sql);
    insertStmt.clearBindings();
    insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
    insertStmt.bindBlob(2, bal);
    insertStmt.executeInsert();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image bytes are very small.  Are you sure that is the whole image? Accoring to your output the image is only 22 bytes and that is small.  I only say this because the API states:

`Returns The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.`

I believe that `image` is not as large as it is supposed to be.

Try to store your image again in the database with this code and try to retrieve again:

```
Bitmap myLogo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.yourBitmap);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
myLogo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
b = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: i think it is the whole image. because when i was encoding it in Base64.encodeBytes(b); the entire image was displaying

Comment: how did you obtain the bytes from the image?

Comment: I took the image from the R.drawable folder and converted them into bytes. please have a look at the edit

Comment: try my new response @Pooja