# Android - converting File or Byte array into a Blob

Tags: android, file, arrays, blob

I've been searching a lot but i couldn't find an answer for this simple question.

I would like to implement one of the following functions:

```
public Blob getBlob(Byte[] imageByteArray){

}

public Blob getBlob(File imageFile){

}
```

please note that these functions are being called from the android client.
thanks!

Comment: Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714700/byte-to-image-android) similar to yours that has been answered...

Answer (score -1):

```
//you bitmap image first get
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images/image.jpg");
//take on bytearrayoutputStream to convert into blolb  so here is you blob
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 "ignore png", blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
```

Comment: if im not mistaken , this function is (File - > byteArray)   and not (File - > Blob)